# How to save and retrieve state variables to session storage with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

I am using **React 18.2.0**, where I have a `BodyComponent` that stores `results` from an API call into states and `filters` that are used in the call.

The `BodyComponent` retrieves the `results` and the `filters` from the Session Storage at load with a hook, and updates the `sessionStorage` when the `results` are updated.

```
export default function BodyComponent(){

    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('results') !== null) {
            setResults(JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('results')));
        }
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('filters') !== null && filters.length === 0) {
            setFilters(JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('filters')));
        }
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('results', JSON.stringify(results));
    }, [results]);

    return (
    ...
    <FilterComponent filters={filters} setFilters={setFilters}/>
    ...
    )

}
```

The filter component updates the filters to the session storage :

```
export default function FilterComponent(props) {
    const {filters, setFilters} = props; 

    useEffect(() => {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('filters', JSON.stringify(filters));
    }, [filters]);

    return (
    ...
    )
}
```

When I navigate to another React route and back to the route that loads `BodyComponent`, `filters` are saved to the session storage, and `BodyComponent` successfully retrieves them and passes them to `FilterComponent` at load.

However, the same is not true for `results`, which are saved to the session storage but not set to their State on load.

I have tried the following :

- handling the states and the sessionStorage on the parent component of BodyComponent, thinking it'd be a problem of asynchronous state updates.
  When I did this, not only it didn't solve the problem, but the filters weren't loaded correctly anymore either.
- Updating the session storage manually everywhere I'm updating it (Which is bad pratice, but i've tried.), thinking it'd be a problem because the hooks don't detect the updates correctly.
  This didn't change anything.
- Copying the useEffect writing to session storage into each Component involved.
  Thid didn't change anything either.

What am I missing?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the problem usgin the code you provided, can you make a working example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: @PauloFernando Yes- Here is the [Reproducted problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-leavitt-5qw0fv), and here [the correction](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-frog-18p6nu) thanks to Olivier Boissé.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(results); // results is empty on the first render 
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('results', JSON.stringify(results));
}, [results]);
```

When the effect is executed for the first time, `results` is empty so you reset your results after the initial render.

From the [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#parameters), `useState` can take an *initializer function* to compute the initial state (this function will be called only once when the component is initialized).

```
function load(key) {
  const item = window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
  return item != null ? JSON.parse(item) : [];
}

export default function BodyComponent(){
    const [results, setResults] = useState(() => load('results'));
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState(() => load('filters'));

    useEffect(() => {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('results', JSON.stringify(results));
    }, [results]);
    
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The problem is caused by the below `useEffect` and how you are initially setting the state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('results', JSON.stringify(results));
}, [results]);
```

The above `useEffect` runs every time `results` changes, but also on mount. And on mount, the state is equal to that initial empty array given to `useState`. So the `sessionStorage` is set to that array.

## Solution

You could prevent the callback from running on the initial render so that you have the time to pick what's in the storage with the help of that other `useEffect`, like so:

```
// Make sure you import useRef from React
const firstRenderRef=useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
    if(firstRenderRef.current){
      firstRenderRef.current=false;
      return;
    }
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('results', JSON.stringify(results));
}, [results])
```

You could have the same logic for `filters` in `FilterComponent`.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't fix my issue. Olivier Boissé's answer did, though.

Comment: Weird, are you sure you did exactly as I did?